# Query JSONB columns with GORM using model

Tags: go-gorm

I have a struct/model

```
type User struct {
        gorm.Model
        Name string         `gorm:"unique;not null" json:"name"`
        Data postgres.Jsonb `json:"data"`
}
```

I can query in postgres

```
db=# select id,name,data from users where data @> '{"foo": "bar"}';
id | name  |       data
----+-------+------------------
6 | user01 | {"foo": "bar"}
7 | user02 | {"foo": "bar"}
8 | user03 | {"foo": "bar"}
```

How do I construct a query on the jsonB column for a particular key(s)?  I was not able to find any documentation for using model objects to query. I understand its possible to do with raw query, but wanted to see how it can be done using model object ie.

```
users := []model.User{}
db.Find(&users, map[string]interface{}{"foo": "bar"})
```

http://gorm.io/docs/dialects.html

http://gorm.io/docs/query.html

Comment: Have you tried `db.Find(&users, "data @> ?", map[string]interface{}{"foo": "bar"})`

Comment: Thanks, I see that this does resolve my question.

Comment: Okay, then i’ll Add this as an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

In your example you are not specifying which field the map will filter. Try

```
db.Find(&users, "data @> ?", map[string]interface{}{"foo": "bar"})
```

Answer (score 3):

You make the query like this :

```
users := []model.User{}
db.Where("data ->> 'foo' = ?", "bar").Find(&users)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this works for jsonp but [datatypes](https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes) worked for me with JSON saved as a string

```golang
import "gorm.io/datatypes"

db.Where(datatypes.JSONQuery("data").Equals("bar", "foo")).Find(&users)
```